# I forgot the password to a cbz/zip file

Tags: backup, password-recovery

I forgot the password to a `cbz` file, which when I open it says it only contains empty pages, so i rename it to `zip`, since I read it will open anyway, and I enter what I supposed to be the password, and it starts extracting some 100 files, but it stops and asks for a password again and none of my known passwords work. Help? it's a backup for over 2 years of work.
I'm using Archive Manager at Ubuntu 13.

Comment: sorry if i'm not a top programmer, I apologize to GOD for that

Comment: I guess the only way to open it is by bruteforcing the password.

Answer (score 4):

What you are left with is trying to "guess" the password using a tool such as `fcrackzip`.

You can install it directly from the Software Center. *Make sure* you read the `man` page:

```
man fcrackzip
```

Example of usage:

```
fcrackzip -b -c aA1 -p foo bar.zip
```

In this example, you'll try to crack the password for file `bar.zip`. With option `-b` you'll perform a search using all possible combination of characters specified; with option `-c aA1` you include all lower-case and upper-case letters as well as all digits; with option `-p foo` you set the initial password as `foo` (if dictionary mode instead of brute-force, `foo` would be the file with list of passwords).